# Lo-Dash array grouping

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I spent hours on the Lo-Dash documentation site now, and can't find a solution for my problem. I don't know how it's called, so it is a bit hard to search for. I basically want to group an array into an object so that duplicate entries are a field while different entries are an array.

For example, I have this array:

```
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'dog' },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'dog' },
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'cat' },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'goldfish' }
];
```

And I want to get this:

```
[
  { name: 'barney',
    age: 42,
    pet: [ 'dog', 'cat' ] },
  { name: 'fred',
    age: 35,
    pet: [ 'dog', 'goldfish' ] }
]
```

Is there a Lo-Dash method for doing this, or do I have to chain several ones? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What did you try that failed?

Comment: just a normal array `.reduce()` will work.

Comment: don't you know what are the keys in your character object, and what could be their values?

Comment: @zerkms I fail to see how... can you show me?

Comment: @Mritunjay I know what my keys are, but not the possible values. How can that help me?

Comment: @Mritunjay I'm getting the array via a REST get. So I don't have control over the values. I'm just trying to find a way to re-group it so that I can handle the objects easier.

Comment: @Terry: in reduce callback you're checking if a user is already in a result array. If they are - add a pet. Or the whole user otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a more lo-dash, underscore way of doing it:

```
var result = _.reduce(characters, function (prev, current) {
    var char = _.find(prev, function (character) {
        return character['name'] === current['name'];
    });

    // Character does not yet exists in the array, push it
    if (char === undefined) {
        prev.push(current);
    } else {
        // If char['pet'] is not an array, create one
        if (!_.isArray(char['pet'])) {
            char['pet'] = [char['pet']];
        }

        // Push the current pets to the founded character
        char['pet'].push(current['pet']);
    }

    return prev;
}, []); // Initialize an empty array for the prev object

console.log(result);
```

Let me know if there is a more awesomeness feature in underscore/lodash :-)!

### Fiddle

Answer (score 8):

Although answered, still a try. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/qx4tajL6/)

```
var characters = [
      { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'dog' },
      { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'dog' },
      { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'cat' },
      { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'goldfish' }
    ];

var result=_.chain(characters).groupBy("name").map(function(v, i) {
      return {
        name: i,
        age: _.get(_.find(v, 'age'), 'age'),
        pet: _.map(v, 'pet')
      }
    }).value();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, '  ') + '</pre>';
```

Comment: It works only for the above example data. It doesn't work if the data is as follows: { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'dog' },
      { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'dog' },
      { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 40,  'pet': 'dog' },
      { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'goldfish' }

Comment: @GaganPrajapati what is the point ? The data is an array of objects. Why are you taking the array notation from the data. Are you trying to use without an array ?

Comment: Sorry, for not making it clear. Actually, it's still an array. I have just changed the pet age to 40 for one of them. So, it should give me 3 objects instead of 2. But, I still get 2 objects and the one with age 40 is still in age 42 object. I have got the solution but read the comment today.

Comment: @GaganPrajapati could you share your snippet in codepen/jsdiffle ? I'm still not clear about the bug.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gaganprajapati/7gbhz9df/4/ I have changed the ages of the pets. So, there should be 4 different groups, but I get only 2. It's not grouping for unique age

Comment: @GaganPrajapati I think you misunderstood OP's question. I get your point, but for dataset why would a person's age be different ? It's barney's entries for different pets. So if we were to find a composite unique on user's name and age, we'll have do another group by i believe. By default Lodash doesn't accept grouping by multiple properties.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. I was looking for grouping using multiple fields.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more elegant and much shorter solution, with chaining:

```js
var characters = [{
    'name': 'barney',
    'age': 42,
    'pet': 'dog'
}, {
    'name': 'fred',
    'age': 35,
    'pet': 'dog'
}, {
    'name': 'barney',
    'age': 42,
    'pet': 'cat'
}, {
    'name': 'fred',
    'age': 35,
    'pet': 'fish'
}];

var result = _(characters).groupBy('name').transform(function(result, current) {
    result.push({
        name: current[0].name,
        age: current[0].age,
        pets: _.map(current, 'pet')
    });
}, []).value();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, '\t') + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something working but I haven't used Lo-Dash for it. So there could be better solutions also.

```
var regroupCharacters = function (characters) {
    var regrouped = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {  //get one character
        var matched = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < regrouped.length; j++) { 
            if(characters[i].name == regrouped[j].name){  // check in each regrouped element if character is there just add the pet 
                matched = true;
                regrouped[j].pets.push(characters[i].pet);
            }
        };
        if(!matched){  // if it is a new character
            var newCharacter = {'name':characters[i].name,'age':characters[i].age,pets:[characters[i].pet]};
            regrouped.push(newCharacter);       
        }
    };
    return regrouped;
}
```

call the function:-

```
var regrouped = regroupCharacters(characters);
```

I've used `pets` as field not `pet` because it is a collection, if you have any problem you can change it.